# Java 8 Version - of Map of Lists with Condition

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to know how to check and retrieve the elements of a `List` inside a `Map`.

```
private Map<User, List<Offer>> shops = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(32);

//how to write this?
public List<Offer> getOffersOlderThan(int seconds){
    return this.shops.values().stream().forEach(
                x->x.stream()
                    .filter(y-> MyTime.currentTime.minusSeconds(seconds)
                                      .isBefore(y.getOfferBegin()))
}
```

I already tried to use a `filter` instead the first `forEach` but that didn't work either.

I want to retrieve the `List` of all `Offer`´s which have an `Timestamp` before `currentTime - seconds`.

How do I return with Java 8 an Generic List? 
 e.g.:

```
public List<Offer> getOffersByUser(User u){
    return this.shops.entrySet().stream().filter(x->x.getKey().getId()==u.getId())
               .collect(List::new) //how to parameterize?
}
```

Comment: How about just using `this.shops.get(u)` to get the offers of a given user? That's what a Map is all about.

Comment: forEach() returns void. So you can't call any method on what forEach() returns. You need to read some documentation.

Comment: @jbn AFAICT OP wants offers from *all* users

Comment: @Bohemian not in the second snippet.

Comment: @JBNizet lol, guess I was too long up. ofc get() is enough....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all Offers, use `flatMap()` and `collect()`

```
return shops.values().stream()
    .flapMap(List::stream)
    .filter(y-> MyTime.currentTime.minusSeconds(seconds).isBefore(y.getOfferBegin())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For only the user's offers:

```
return shops.getOrDefault(user, Collections.emptyList())
    .filter(y-> MyTime.currentTime.minusSeconds(seconds).isBefore(y.getOfferBegin())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So as a Rule of Thumb I should always use flatMap() when I have an Collection inside an Collection because this is "returning" only the inner Collection?

Comment: `flatMap()` turns elements of the stream into (sub)streams, which are concatenated to form a single final stream. You provide `flatMap()` the function to produce a stream from an element. So, yes it's a good rule of thumb.